# Nextflow Does Not Pull "latest" Docker Image

Tags: docker, jenkins, nextflow

I am running two VMs. One VM is used for running nextflow, on the other VM there is a Jenkins build server. Jenkins is responsible for building new Docker images and pushing new Docker images to our private google container registry.

My `nextflow.config` file looks something like this:

```
process {
    withLabel: awesome_image {
        container = "eu.gcr.io/best-project-1234/coolest_os:latest"
    }
}
```

After building a new image using the Jenkins server I was running a new nextflow script and I noticed that nextflow was still using the old image. After some research (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58539792/1820480), I realized that this has to do with the fact that I am using the `latest` tag, and since there is already an image called latest on the nextflow VM, nextflow uses that one and does not bother checking the registry.

Question: How can I ensure that before every run of nextflow, it checks the registry for newer images? Or, is there a script/program that I can run on the VM that checks the registry (instead of nextflow)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nextflow just runs your command(s) in a container using `docker run`. If you specify an image that you haven't pulled yet, `docker run` will first do a `docker pull` to download/localize the image. To check the registry again for newer images, you'll just need to make sure you call `docker pull` (for each image) before running Nextflow. If you want to instead check the registry for newer images each time a process is spawned, please see below.

After some research, it looks like the latest Docker cli (v20.10.0) now has a flag to modify the pull behavior when running containers:

```
--pull string   Pull image before running ("always"|"missing"|"never") (default "missing")
```

This is nice because it means it should now be possible pass this through in your `nextflow.config`:

```
docker {
    enabled = true
    runOptions = '--pull=always'
}
```

But this will have the overhead of doing a `docker pull` for each process spawned and, depending on when new images are pushed to your registry, may mean some processes get different containers during your workflow execution. This may not be a concern though if you only need the 'latest' containers and do not care for reproducibility.